# Snap to mesh issues with Z and X axis constraints

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have two meshes that I've joined to a single object.  I'm attempting to use the snap to mesh feature for each of the 6 vertices on the face of mesh 1 to snap them to different faces/edges on mesh 2.

I select the vertex I want to move, press <kbd>Y</kbd> to constrain movement to only the Y-axis, and then it slides smoothly along the Y, not snapping to the face.  Is this behavior intentional?  Is there a better way to do what I'm doing while maintaining precision?

I'm using Blender 2.6.

[image: The two meshes]
[image: My settings for snapping to mesh]
[image: Vertex not snapping to face]

Comment: *IIRC* There is a bug in 2.69 (now fixed in the development versions) which makes face snapping not work in orthographic view. Try it in perspective view if you haven't already (it's hard to tell from your screenshots)

Comment: I was in ortho, but switching to persp doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Hm.. What happens if you try it in a later version (2.69 is the latest) or a development version? (everything looks right, so I'm inclined to think it's a bug)

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be fixed in latest snapshot on master branch.  Thanks for the responses, though.

Comment: Perhaps you could upload a .blend where this is happening? It works fine for me using the same settings. [Here is a file](http://pasteall.org/blend/26614) where it's working.

Comment: Here's the [file from my screenshots](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26621).  Moving the selected vertex to the left, constrained to only Y movement, until it snaps to the face it's lined up with on that axis.  Other snap to mesh options seem to work fine, but it seems to just not attempt to snap to anything as soon as I constrain it to Y.  A friend made a nearly identical set of meshes from scratch and found the same behavior.  Maybe it refuses because of it causing the meshes to intersect for some reason?  Maybe it's related to the normals of the faces somehow?  I have no idea at this point.

Comment: Very odd... You could try [posting a bug report](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/599) with that file.

Comment: I tried playing with both files as well. Couldn't figure out why Fen's file doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to solve this (that may work), using the shrinkwrap modifier. Do this before joining the objects.

- Create a vertex group with the vertices you want to snap.
- Add a shrinkwrap modifier.
- Set your vertex group as the one affected.
- Set mode to "Project".
- Select the axis to project along.
- Tick both positive and negative (maybe you need to do this).

Like this:

[image: shrinkwrap]